# Nilpotent map when rank is 1 to prove image is in the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For a nilpotent map $A\colon k^n \to k^n$ of rank 1,
 prove that $\operatorname{Im}A \subset \ker A$.

I took an element $y$ of the image and try to prove that element in the kernel.
Here I come to $A(A(y)$, but I don't know how to complete and don't know how to use the map's $\text{rank} =1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \operatorname{Im}(A)$ which is not trivial, $A(x)=cx$ since the rank is one, it implies $A^n(x)=c^nx=0$ since $A$ is nilpotent, we deduce that $c^n=c=0$, $x\in \ker(A)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(A)=\operatorname{Vec}(x)\subset \ker(A)$.